# Can't allow users to log in via SSH (Bash, OpenSSH, CentOS 6.5)

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, rsa

I am running a CentOS 6.5 machine remotely via SSH. I use RSA keys and have disabled password authentication. The problem that I am having is that whenever I add a new user and want him/her to log in via SSH, they are denied access.

At first this seemed like a simple problem. Theses are what I have already tried:

- Checked the pub key for obvious errors
- Ensured the right permissions on authorized_keys and ~/.ssh
- Made sure they're in the AllowUsers list in ssh_config
- Checked firewall permissions
- Made sure their private key is being used
- Restarted SSHD

Here is what I have set in `sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers keving moman muser
```

And this is what my log is telling me:

```
Login attempted when not in AllowUsers list:
    muser : 3 Time(s)
    root : 127 Time(s)
```

Why is SSH not allowing login while the AllowUsers list obviously lists muser? Is there another place where this could be set?

UPDATE: I attempted a login to that account on my machine after adding my pub key to the user's authorized_keys file with the verbose flag `-v`. These are the results (with a fake IP and server host key for security reasons):

```
$ ssh -v mattm@111.111.111.111
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/config
debug1: Connecting to 111.111.111.111 [111.111.111.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA [censored]
debug1: Host '111.111.111.111' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: Did you restart sshd?

Comment: If you have a Linux client, what happens if you turn on verbose logging (-v).  Similarly, are you in a position to run sshd in the foreground with logging ?   Lastly, did you restart SSH after modifying AllowUsers ?

Comment: @davidgo I updated the question with the putput you mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sure did.

Comment: Can you post the output from /var/log/secure through a login attempt?

Comment: @toppledwagon This was the ticket, log said bad permissions. However .ssh was set to 700 and authorized_keys was set to 600, the problem came from the home directory itself having group write permissions. That's another problem, though. I was able to log in after this. Add this as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Check your /var/log/secure for clues.

Comment: Check this post if your log comes up with permission issues http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @toppledwagon suggests in the comments to my question, I checked `/var/log/security` and sure enough there was an entry for bad permissions on the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` tree including the home directory.

After making these edits I was able to log in to the user's account via ssh with RSA keys:

```
$ chmod g-w /home/your_user
$ chmod 700 /home/your_user/.ssh
$ chmod 600 /home/your_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Ref: http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/

After adjusting these permissions I was able to log in. It was interesting to note that I had the `.ssh` dir and `authorized_keys` file already set to `700` and `600` respectively. For some reason the home directory was not set properly.

Thanks to all who helped in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

1. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` add the group of your user to `AllowGroups`.
2. Restart sshd `service sshd restart`